# How do you git show untracked files that do not exist in .gitignore

Tags: git

I'm using `git status -u` to show untracked files. And on the terminal, I see plenty untracked files that I need to be untracked such as unit tests, personal documentation, etc. I have put them in `.gitignore`, but it seems that `git status` still shows them.

How do you show only untracked files that don't exist in `.gitignore`.

Comment: if untracked files are shown in git status, they are not ignored by .gitignore properly. can you show you working directory structure and .gitignore contents?

Comment: Agree with @max, it should work. Here's a wild guess: if you're on Windows, be aware that .gitignore, unlike Windows, is case-sensitive. So if you ignore *.txt and there's a Test.TXT on disk, it won't be ignored.

Answer (score 369):

You can explicitly list what is being tracked and untracked as follows to see if Git is seeing and honoring your `.gitignore`. If you post your `.gitignore` contents, `git status` output, and `dir` or `ls` we can better assist you.

#### List ignored files

```
$ git ls-files . --ignored --exclude-standard --others
```

#### List untracked files

```
$ git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others
```

Comment: If you see files that you didn't think were in your .gitignore, there may be another one hiding in your project. Ferret it out with ` find . -name .gitignore`.

Comment: @matthew-mccullough Great answer!  I'll be adding some aliases for these thanks!  @jpadvo Can you give example of useage for `find` method?

Comment: If you want a short list, say you're ignoring node_modules and don't want to see the whole tree, add `--directory` so only the top-level folder being ignored will be printed (this is closer to git status).

Comment: To make it clear, `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --ignored` lists untracked ignored files, and `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard` untracked not ignored ones. More on it [here](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/06fc5dc1b8804f1204e4d615fd0d6b51).

Comment: Note that by default `git ls-files --others` does not list empty directories. To list empty directories add the `--directory` option. This is not obvious from the man page but can be deduced. `--directory`: _If a whole directory is classified as "other", show just its name (with a trailing slash) and not its whole contents._. `--no-empty-directory`: _Do not list empty directories. Has no effect without --directory._

Answer (score -8):

Use:

```
git config status.showuntrackedfiles no
```

Comment: On the current release version of git, I get `error: Invalid untracked files mode 'yes'` when I try to use that.

Comment: Possible values are `no`, `normal`, `all`. It's explained here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score -8):

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your answer