# Show changes not staged for commit in git

Tags: git

I have a particular issue that I'm working on where I need to parse the changes ***NOT*** staged for commit.

If you do `git status --porcelain` you can get an output like this:

```
M  change1
M  change2
MM change3
 M change4
 M change5
```

Changes 1 and 2 are staged, changes 3 to 5 are not. `MM` means something else I haven't looked at yet.

I can parse this output, but I am wondering if there's a better way to just show the files in the "**Changes not staged for commit**" category of `git status`.

Answer (score 12):

You can get which *tracked* files have unstaged changes with `git diff --name-only` or `git ls-files . -m`.

You can get *untracked but not ignored* files with `git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others`. ([From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855096/14660)).

Put them together to get all files which are not ignored and are untracked or have unstaged changes.

```
git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others -m
```

Answer (score 2):

The `MM` state means there are some changes staged, and some changes not-staged.

More precisely, it means that the index version of that path differs from the `HEAD` version—this is the first `M`—and that the work-tree version of that path differs from the index version.

For instance, suppose you have a README and you stage a change:

```
$ echo stuff >> README; git add README; git status --porcelain
M  README
```

Now you make a second change to the same file.  To make it especially interesting, let's remove the added `stuff` line:

```
$ ed README << 'end'
$d
w
q
end
2634
2628
$ git status --porcelain
MM README
```

Now if we `git add` the file, this stages the work-tree version which is the same as the `HEAD` version, and:

```
$ git add README
$ git status --porcelain
$
```

> I can parse this output, but I am wondering if there's a better way to just show the files in the "Changes not staged for commit" of 'git status'.

You need to decide what to do about files in this state, and if there is the potential for unmerged states—if there may be files that have not yet had a conflicted merge resolved, these are the unmerged files—what to do for them as well.

In general, though, if you want a *diff*, use `git diff`.  There are many sub-flavors of `diff`: you can compare a tree (such as that for `HEAD`) to the index, or to the work-tree, or compare two trees to each other.  See [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) for details, but in short `git diff` compares the index to the work-tree and hence corresponds to the second column of the status output.

To get diff to emit only the names of the files, use `--name-only`.  So `git diff --name-only` will give you changes you *could* stage.  (This doesn't help with untracked files; see [Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33426799/1256452) for using `git ls-files` for that.)

Comment: I think the questioner already knows how `git status --porcelain` works. They're asking for a better way to list files which have changed.

Comment: I was filling in the `MM` state here and I accidentally got the partial post posted before I finished it (cat on keyboard!).