# How to find private files in git repo which is equvalent of private files in clearcase/cleartool?

Tags: git, clearcase, cleartool

I am using git for scm ofmy C project.
What is the command to find all the files which are generated during build of the project like .o and .so files ?
What I am asking is same as private files in in cleartool/clearcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by listing ignored files, as I proposed in  2009:

```
git ls-files -o -i --exclude-standard
```

That is because those generated files are supposed to be in a `.gitignore` file.

The more general list is [the untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855096/6309)

```
git ls-files -o --exclude-standard
```

That would be the closed of the `ct ls-private` I mentioned in 2013 with "[ClearCase delete view private files only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15811695/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command.

Git has no idea about the usage of different files. You tell git to track a file - it will track its history. How you locate those files will depend on your individual project (Makefiles, XCode/VisualStudio configuration etc.).

It is however possible to configure git to ignore such files using a `.gitignore` file. See the documentation for more info: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore