# Git status show all untracked file instead of ./

Tags: git

How do i force `git status` to show all untracked files instead of just showing "./" ?

For context, i created two new files: server.py and requirements.txt. I thought `git status` will list all new file as usual, but what happened is that git only shows "./" instead of listing all untracked file.

[image]

From the answers at [How do you git show untracked files that do not exist in .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538144/how-do-you-git-show-untracked-files-that-do-not-exist-in-gitignore) , i can show all the files with the command `git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others`

[image]

This is very inconvenient, because i had to run two command instead of just `git status`. I wonder what causes `git status` to only show "./" instead of listing all the untracked file? Is there any way to force `git status` to list all untracked files ?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-statusshowUntrackedFiles Since you always want this behavior, the correct approach is to use `git config` to set `status.showUntrackedFiles` to all. Example: `git config --global status.showUntrackedFiles all` That way, simply saying `git status` will always do what you want. Note however that this behavior (no matter how you ask for it) is expensive, as explained by the docs. You will perhaps find that `git status` is a lot slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying the command like this: `git status --untracked-files=all`